# Laravel Many To Many (Polymorphic) issue

Tags: laravel, model, polymorphism, eloquent-relationship

I've been trying to create a Many To Many (Polymorphic) system that saves the state of every update done by a specific user on specific Models (for instance: `Company`, `Address`, `Language` models) with a `note` field and the `updated_by`. The goal is to keep track of who updated the model and when, and the `note` field is a text field that states where in the system the model was updated.

Below is what I created, but I'm open to getting a different solution that, in the end, allows me to accomplish the goal described above.

I've created the model `Update` (`php artisan make:model Update -m`) with the migration:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 * @since
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('updates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->comment('The record ID');
        $table->bigInteger('updatable_id')->unsigned()->comment('THe model record id');
        $table->string('updatable_type')->comment('THe model name');
        $table->string('note')->nullable()->comment('The record note');
        $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable()->comment('The user ID which updated the record');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

On the model `Update` all the `$fillable`, `$dates` properties are standard, and the method of the `Update` model:

```
class Update extends Model
{
    /**
     * Method to morph the records
     *
     * @access public
     */
    public function updatable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

After trying several ways on the different models, my difficulty is getting the relation because when I **save to the** `updates` table, **it saves correctly**. For instance, in the **Company** model: `Company::where('id', 1)->with('updates')->get();` as in the model `Company` I have the method:

```
public function updates()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Update::class, 'updatable', 'updates')->withPivot(['note', 'updated_by'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Most certainly, I'm doing something wrong because when I call `Company::where('id', 1)->with('updates')->get();` it throws an SQL error "Not unique table/alias".

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you considered `update` is a reserved name in SQL?

Comment: Hmmm... that's a good point I did not consider. I'll try to change the name and post it here if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Changed the Update model name to TrackChange (table: track_changes) set to trackable and the same error.

Comment: The only problem I see is the confusion with `morphToMany` while using a table name called `updates`. The `morphMany` would use a table name called `updates`, `morphToMany` would be using the table name `updatables`. So at the end you are using two different tables with the same name, hence `(Update::class, 'updatable', 'updates')` should be using the `updatables` table, not the `updates` table. If you would just return `$this->morphToMany(Update::class, 'updatable')` it will try to reach a table called `updateables` where `morphMany(Update::class, 'updatable')` should work with your setup.

Comment: I'll try to conclude this in an answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see here is using `morphToMany` instead of `morphMany`.

`return $this->morphToMany(Update::class, 'updateable', 'updates');` will use the intermediate table (and alias) `updates` (3rd argument) instead of using the default table name `updateables`. Here it will clash with the table (model) `updates`, so it will produce the error you are receiving.

`return $this->morphMany(Update::class, 'updateable');` will use the table `updates` and should work with your setup.

Do notice that `morphMany` does not work with collecting pivot fields (e.g. `withPivot([..])`, it's not an intermediate table. Only `morphToMany` does.

Comment: First, thank you for your valuable help @dbf! Made those changes, and suddenly I found one small error in my fields.
I had `updatable_id` instead of `updateable_id` and `updatable_type` instead of `updateable_type`. It was missing the 'e'. Now it works.
Thank you!